# COBOL program syntax errors - unexpected identifiers

Tags: syntax, cobol

I am trying to get this COBOL program running for a school assignment, but am having issues compiling that I can't find the cause for.  The code is:

```
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT INFILE ASSIGN TO "C:\home\josh\DataFiles\
      -         "Assignment#6_WeeklySalaryDataFile.dat"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
           SELECT OUTPUT-FILE-A ASSIGN TO "C:\DataFiles\Salesperson
      -         "Recognition.rpt"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
           SELECT OUTPUT-FILE-B ASSIGN TO "C:\DataFiles\Salary
      -         "Expense.rpt"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  INFILE.
       01  INPUT-RECORD.
           05  EMPLOYEE-ID              PIC X(4).
           05  JOB-CODE                 PIC X.
           05  LAST-NAME                PIC X(14).
           05  FIRST-NAME               PIC X(14).
           05  START-DATE               PIC X(8).
           05  STORE-NUMBER             PIC X(4).
           05  WEEKLY-SALARY            PIC 9(6).
           05  SALES-AMOUNT             PIC 9(7).
       FD  OUTPUT-FILE-A.
       01  OUTPUT-RECORD-A.
           05  LAST-NAME-A              PIC X(14).
           05  FIRST-NAME-A             PIC X(14).
           05  STORE-NUMBER-A           PIC X(4).
       FD  OUTPUT-FILE-B.
       01  OUTPUT-RECORD-B.
           05  STORE-NUMBER-B           PIC X(4).
           05  JOB-CODE-B               PIC X.
           05  TOTAL-SALARY             PIC 9(4)V99.

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  PRESENT-DATE               PIC X(8).
       01  STORE1-M-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE1-S-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE1-A-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE1-C-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE2-M-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE2-S-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE2-A-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE2-C-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE3-M-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE3-S-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE3-A-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.
       01  STORE3-C-TOTAL             PIC 9(4)V99.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           OPEN INPUT INFILE
           OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE-A
           OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE-B
           MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO PRESENT-DATE
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-A FROM "Employee recognition for the 
      -     "week ending: " PRESENT-DATE  (line 61/62)
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-A FROM "--------------------------------
      -     "--------------------"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-A FROM "Last Name  First 
      -     "Name  Store #"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-A FROM "--------------------------------
      -     "--------------------"
           READ INFILE 
               AT END
                   GO TO END-READ
           PERFORM UNTIL INFILE **(line 72)**
               NOT AT END       **(line 73)**
               MOVE INPUT-RECORD TO OUTPUT-RECORD-A
                   IF JOB-CODE = 'S' AND
                       SALES-AMOUNT > 100000
                   THEN
                       WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-A
                   END-IF
                   IF STORE-NUMBER = '0001'
                   THEN
                       IF JOB-CODE = 'M'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE1-M-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'S'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE1-S-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'A'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE1-A-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'C'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE1-C-TOTAL
                       END-IF
                   ELSE IF STORE-NUMBER = '0002'
                   THEN
                       IF JOB-CODE = 'M'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE2-M-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'S'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE2-S-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'A'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE2-A-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'C'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE2-C-TOTAL
                       END-IF
                   ELSE IF STORE-NUMBER = '0003'
                   THEN
                       IF JOB-CODE = 'M'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE3-M-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'S'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE3-S-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'A'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE3-A-TOTAL
                       ELSE IF JOB-CODE = 'C'
                       THEN
                           ADD WEEKLY-SALARY TO STORE3-C-TOTAL
                       END-IF
                   END-IF
                   READ INFILE AT END
                       GO TO END-READ
               END-PERFORM
           END-READ.  (line 130)
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Salary expense for the week 
      -     "ending: " 
               PRESENT-DATE   (line 133)
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "--------------------------------
      -     "--------------------"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "STORE #1"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Management: " STORE1-M-TOTAL**(line137)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Sales: " STORE1-S-TOTAL **(line 138)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Admin: " STORE1-A-TOTAL **(line 139)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Custodial: " STORE1-C-TOTAL **(line 140)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "-------------------------------
      -     "---------------------"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "STORE #2"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Management: " STORE2-M-TOTAL **(line 144)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Sales: " STORE2-S-TOTAL **(line 145)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Admin: " STORE2-A-TOTAL **(line 146)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Custodial: " STORE2-C-TOTAL **(l 147)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "--------------------------------
      -     "--------------------"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "STORE #3"
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Management: " STORE3-M-TOTAL **(l 151)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Sales: " STORE3-S-TOTAL  **(line 152)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Admin: " STORE3-A-TOTAL **(line 153)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "Custodial: " STORE3-C-TOTAL **(line 154)**
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD-B FROM "--------------------------------
      -     "--------------------"
           CLOSE INFILE, OUTPUT-FILE-A, OUTPUT-FILE-B
           STOP RUN.

       end program Assignment6.
```

and the errors I am receiving are:

> Assign6.cbl:61: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:72: error: 'INFILE' is not a field

> Assign6.cbl:73: error: syntax error, unexpected NOT END

> Assign6.cbl:130: error: syntax error, unexpected END-READ

> Assign6.cbl:133: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:137: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:138: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:139: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:140: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:144: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:145: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:146: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:147: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:151: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:152: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:153: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

> Assign6.cbl:154: error: syntax error, unexpected Identifier

mostly the issue is my variables, though there is also the INFILE not being a field and unexpected `NOT END` and `END-READ` - not really sure what is causing these, any advice is appreciated.

I've tried looking for answers based on the errors given but nothing comes up with the same type of issue, and those that are similar have solutions that don't work for me - for example many other questions have an "expecting" phrase suggesting what is missing as part of the error, while my errors just say it's unexpected with no suggestion regarding *why* it's wrong.

Comment: Missing: what line _is_ line 61? As you seem to us GnuCOBOL you may want to use `-t problem.lst -tlines=0` to get a source listing with line numbers and embedded diagnostics to share instead.

Note: the string continuation in COBOL85 style will get you a lot of spaces (up to the max chars), you may want to try COBOL2002 style `"some"-  "literal"` or  `"concatenated" & "strings"`.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Hey Simon, thanks for the reply.  For the missing line numbers I edited and added in the line numbers on the relevant lines.  
As to your other suggestions, I am very new to COBOL and couldn't find anything regarding using "-t problem.lst tlines=0" in the terminal online - any further advice around that would be appreciated if it would help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using standard COBOL, so you need to respect some areas (column limits), and the continuation rules. For more information see  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.1?topic=b-continuation-lines.

```
Column 1-6: reserved for line numbers (you can use it for short marks, too) - it's ignored by the compiler
Column 7: used for comment mark(*) or continuation mark(-)
Column 8-11: area A, reserved for declarations, like divisions, sections, variable declaration (levels 01, 77)
Column 12-72: area B, reserved for instructions (variable declarations can start at area B (level 02 and so on).
```

When using continuation lines, all characters left blank until 72th column will be concatenated with the next line. In your example, this is what you're getting for INFILE assignment "C:\home\josh\DataFiles\BBBBBBBBBBBBAssignment#6_WeeklySalaryDataFile.dat", where BBBBBBBBBBBB are blanks (space characters).

Try this instead:

```
       SELECT INFILE ASSIGN TO "C:\home\josh\DataFiles\Assignment#6_
  -         "WeeklySalaryDataFile.dat"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```

Do the same for another continuation lines in your code. I hope this help you.

Comment: And you need to respect that it's correctly spelled **column** - it neither has two "l" nor two "m" .....